# android:How to set multiple values from same column to a String[] or ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, string, arraylist

```
private ArrayList<String> names;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name from dog",null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
   names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

I'm trying to get multiple values from the same column in database,but I don't know how to set them dynamically to a String[] or ArrayList.Because the data number is dynamically,so a little confused.I'm not sure the code i just wrote is right.

Comment: What output do you get if you Log to the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right, except that you didn't initialize your list:

```
names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Yeah,this works.It's just I can't update my list view when i get data in this way,I thought there may be something wrong with it.

Comment: You probably need to refresh the list view's adapter then.